# SLF4J and Gradle - don't see any logs

Tags: android, maven, gradle, slf4j

Recently I've decided to move my Android project from Maven to gradle. Unfortunately, logger which I used - SLF4J - doesn't work anymore.

Gradle project is synced properly, and I have access to SLF4J library, but I can't see any logs in logcat.

At official SFL4J website I found that nothing special changed between Maven and Gradle using of it (only semantic of adding dependencies). Any idea where should I look for and answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of research finally I found a solution. 'Workaround' to be fair. SLF4J-android doesn't work properly, when we add latest version from maven central repository - v1.7.7. With release candidate version, everything works as expected - v1.6.1-RC1.

To be honest, I've got in trouble by melf - I've updated used version of slf4j-android from RC to newest version in the middle of migrating from Maven to Gradle process.

I've realized that slf4j-android v1.7.7 shows 'info' logs properly and there are some problems with 'debug' logs. This problem is linked to wrong logs level set for debug logs (VERBOSE) and it is reported [bug](http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=315).